# How can I put Amazon example-dataset in a spark movie-recommendation in spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I want to put Amazon data(metadata.json) in the spark example movie-recommendation

Movie-recommendations use the following format, but Amazon data uses a string instead of an integer

Below is a source of movie-recommendations.

```
UserID::MovieID::Rating::Timestamp // ratings.dat format
MovieID::Title::Genres // movies.dat format

val ratings = sc.textFile(new File(movieLensHomeDir, "ratings.dat").toString).map { line =>
  val fields = line.split("::")
  // format: (timestamp % 10, Rating(userId, movieId, rating))
  (fields(3).toLong % 10, Rating(fields(0).toInt, fields(1).toInt, fields(2).toDouble))
}

val movies = sc.textFile(new File(movieLensHomeDir, "movies.dat").toString).map { line =>
  val fields = line.split("::")
  // format: (movieId, movieName)
  (fields(0).toInt, fields(1))
}.collect().toMap
```

[spark MLlib example - Movie Recommendation]

https://databricks-training.s3.amazonaws.com/movie-recommendation-with-mllib.html

And this is the Amazon dataset

```
{
  "asin": "0000031852",
  "title": "Girls Ballet Tutu Zebra Hot Pink",
  "price": 3.17,
  "imUrl": "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51fAmVkTbyL._SY300_.jpg",
  "related":
  {
    "also_bought": ["B00JHONN1S", "B002BZX8Z6"],
    "also_viewed": ["B002BZX8Z6", "B00JHONN1S", "B008F0SU0Y", "B00D23MC6W",    "bought_together": ["B002BZX8Z6"]
  },
  "salesRank": {"Toys & Games": 211836},
  "brand": "Coxlures",
  "categories": [["Sports & Outdoors", "Other Sports", "Dance"]]
}
{
    ...
}
```

[amazon review dataset - metadata]

@@@@@@@@@@@@@  SUMMARY  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@

1. I want to parse this json file and put it in the spark example.
   and do not know change the stringID(asin,title,...) to a unique integerID and how to get results
2. I proceeded to parse the SQLparser, but suddenly it does not work and I want to know another way.
   At first it did not happen, but could suddenly occured error because maybe the jsonfile format is broken?

   [SQLContext_error.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDyO0.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark does not work with typical json files. Spark expects json files with each line as a complete json object. That's why regular multi array json files are failed, and you get a [_corrupt_record:String]. So, you have to change json a little bit so that Spark. I modified your json file and it works without any issue -

```
{"asin": "0000031852", "title": "Girls Ballet Tutu Zebra Hot Pink", "price": 3.17,"imUrl": "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51fAmVkTbyL._SY300_.jpg","related": {  "also_bought": ["B00JHONN1S", "B002BZX8Z6"],    "also_viewed":["B002BZX8Z6", "B00JHONN1S", "B008F0SU0Y", "B00D23MC6W"],    "bought_together": ["B002BZX8Z6"]  },  "salesRank": {"Toys & Games": 211836},  "brand": "Coxlures",  "categories": [["Sports & Outdoors", "Other Sports", "Dance"]]}    
{"asin": "0000031853", "title": "AmazonTitle", "price": 5.20,"imUrl": "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51fAmVkTbyL._SY300_.jpg","related": {  "also_bought": ["B00JHONN1S", "B002BZX8Z6"],    "also_viewed":["B002BZX8Z6", "B00JHONN1S", "B008F0SU0Y", "B00D23MC6W"],    "bought_together": ["B002BZX8Z6"]  },  "salesRank": {"Toys & Games": 211836},  "brand": "Coxlures",  "categories": [["Sports & Outdoors", "Other Sports", "Dance"]]}
```

Following is the code & output.

```
val rdd= sqlContext.read.json("metadata.json")
rdd: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [asin: string, brand: string, categories: array<array<string>>, imUrl: string, price: double, related: struct<also_bought:array<string>,also_viewed:array<string>,bought_together:array<string>>, salesRank: struct<Toys & Games:bigint>, title: string
```

Comment: I'm sorry, can i ask you again? I checked my json file.
{
{The format you modified},
{same format}
}
but it does not read.

I think sometimes this data does not include [related] 
in that case sql parser get [_corrupt_record:String]
or first and last '{' , '}' causes trouble...

Comment: Can you provide complete json file. Also, have you tried to modify it as I recommended - Spark expects json files with each line as a complete json object. That's why regular multi array json files are failed.